# Compare two columns and echo duplicates

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a database of 80.000 records with two columns: **uuid** and **sign_in_ip**. Sometimes, when users have multiple accounts they have one sign_in_ip, but more than one UUIDs. Is there any way to easily select only those records?

Comment: Can you show your SQL with your table names and column names so that we take take it to next step.

Comment: You should try to show what are you working on, what's your code, issues and users will try to find a solution.

Comment: It's just one table with two columns - uuid and sign_in_ip. What I want to do is to select all records that have one sign_in_ip but multiple uuid's. When I have the UUIDs I will know how many users and which users have multiple accounts.

Comment: Sample input and expected output would be a big help.

Comment: Sorry to be the noob here, but I posted everything I need in the @Stanislav post comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, this can be done via inner query, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtablename 
WHERE sign_in_ip IN (
        SELECT sign_in_ip 
          FROM yourtablename 
          GROUP BY sign_in_ip 
          HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT uuid) > 1
);
```

Here you selects all records with sing_in_ip which appears more then once. And to find this not unique sign_in_ip's is inner query used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem I didn't mention though is that the "yourtablename" shows the log, which means that every time a user is logging in it leaves a record. So one user with one UUID can leave multiple records. But what we want to do is to extinguish those by UUIDs and Unique IP. 

If we have 1 user logging in twice on the same account then we would have:
`uuid: 123123, ip: 127.0.0.1`
`uuid: 123123, ip: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: But if we have 1 user logging in twice on different accounts we would have:
`uuid: 123123, sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1` and 
`uuid: 321321, sign_in_ip: 127.0.0.1`

And I want to show all UUIDs that comes up more than once with the same IP.

Comment: @Maciej updated my answer, now it has to ignore the same uuids

Comment: @Maciej you are welcome) if solution works, you can accept an answer or upvote it to make it easier for someone to find the answer to the similar question in future